# Call user defined function on click in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have made a jQuery function and want to call it on click event. My code is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $.fn.my_function = function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                alert("Hello");
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_buttom').my_function(); 
    });
</script>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (function($){
        $.fn.my_function = function(options){
            var callback = function(){
                alert("Hello");
                //codes goes here
            };
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).click(callback);
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_buttom').my_function(); 
    });
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer and its working fine.
I have one more question: How should I call a function inside delegate? Is there anything like: `$('body').delegate('#submit_button', my_function());`

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $.fn.my_function = function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                  alert("Hello");
                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_buttom').my_function(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer and its working fine as well.
I have one more question: How should I call a function inside delegate? Is there anything like: `$('body').delegate('#submit_button', my_function());`

Comment: Just declare the function outside like: function Hello() { alert("Hello"); } and the use the function name as the delegate eg.: $("#button").click(Hello); or am I missunderstanding your question ?

Comment: Yeah you didn't get my question :).
Actually my button is coming dynamically so to add any event or to use if I have to use delegate like `$('body').delegate('#submit_button', 'click', function(){});` but here I want to call my_function() when I click that button. _Now you get what I want to say?_

Comment: If you are using latest jquery version (1.7) then you should use On() instead. I'm still not sure I understand what you mean, but if you just want to call a function declared somewhere else it's the same solution as my previous comment. $("body").on("click", "#submit_button", Hello);

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler:

```
$('#submit_buttom').click(function(){
    // Can be any function call, but must be within an asynchronous/anonymous function 
    my_function();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .click() function: [described here on the Getting started with jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery)